# how to publish a .jar file to nexus

Tags: java, gradle, build, nexus, nexus3

I just build a Gradle project which resulted me with a .jar file. But now, when I want to publish it to the nexus repository, I am unable to do so. Here is my build script

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}

System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'nexus'
            url "https://54.89.194.112:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '5.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The output says : Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

I tried all the above steps, but it ended up the same.

Comment: is that the complete error message? Your repository is probably not configured for HTTPS.

Comment: verify SSL is in fact enabled using nmap `$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8081 54.89.194.112`